# How I can add information to test when it run with mvn and in jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, logging, jenkins

I have unit tests in Java, and I want to add some information on the test to the log.

I want to do it with Maven - `mvn clean install –Pstaging`, and also in Jenkins

I tried to do it with `Logger`:

```
       private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(S2STest.class); and then  
     LOG.info("message")
```

and Added it to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

However, I didn't see any information when I run the test.

How I can add information to the test in Maven and Jenkins?

Comment: I believe `System.out` and `System.err` get output - have you tested that?

Comment: it didnt work for me why the logger didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins doesn't include an SLF4J implementation by default. You can see that [in their `pom`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/pom.xml):

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

So, what you need to do is include your own SLF4J implementation in your own pom, such as [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), OR configure it to use the `slf4j-jdk14` implementation by using [`Logger.addHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#addHandler(java.util.logging.Handler)). In the first two cases, you will also have to configure that framework's appropriate configuration files as well.

Once you have turned on whichever of these logging frameworks you've decided, you will be able to use that configuration to generate a target for the logging information, and you will have the file. However, getting into the details of *exactly how to do* that is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow; I recommend picking one and reading their tutorials.

Comment: What is wrong with my Logger ? I also add it the pom.xml                                                                  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.6</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: That is not one of the three choices I suggested you use. SLF4J is an **interface** ONLY. You need an implementation. Try adding [this snippet to your pom](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.3) and then [read this part of the manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: is it ok to use SLF4J?

Comment: @user1365697 SLF4J is an **interface**; because it is an interface, it is **insufficent by itself.** [The Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) serves as a **simple facade** or abstraction for various logging frameworks (e.g. java.util.logging, logback, log4j) allowing the end user to **plug in the desired logging framework** at deployment time.](http://www.slf4j.org/)